# TreeView/TreeViewItem ControlTemplates with dotted lines

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

This seems like it should have such a simple solution, but apparently it doesn't.

I've searched far and wide, and there apparently seems to be no way of adding dotted lines to connect nodes in a `TreeView`, unlike the WinForms equivalent.

I've found a number of sources online where people have changed the ControlTemplate to one which has the connecting lines.  However, when reading through the comments and discussions they all seem to have problems.

How would I go about changing the ControlTemplate to achieve this?

Comment: I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/30cb182c-9419-40bd-946e-87971515fb95/) and tried it, it works.

Comment: @JohanLarsson Thanks for the suggestion, however I'm not really sure how to go about implementing that. Is it just a matter of copy-pasting the code?

Comment: It worked when I copy-pasted but I did not love it, gonna try to make my own deriving from that. Meanwhile you can play with [this](https://github.com/JohanLarsson/Misc/tree/master/WpfTreeViewMisc) dummy app

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As promised I wrote the Control Template to make a WPF TreeView look like the Winform TreeView.

You'll find all the code and files [here](http://intuitiveprogramming.wordpress.com/2012/12/07/how-to-get-the-winform-treeview-style-in-wpf/) or [here](http://mongoose.codeplex.com/) !

Enjoy !

[image]

Comment: codeplex Link is broken